# How can I get the Domain.ext from url? PHP prase

Tags: php, apache, apache2

if we have

```
 $url = "http://subdomain.domin.ext/somepath/file.php";
```

how to get the domain.ext

when I used

```
 $parse = parse_url($url);
 $domin = $parse[host];
```

then 
`echo "$domain"; //this returns subdomain.domin.ext`

is there any idea to get domain.ext?

Comment: How do you define "domain.ext"? "The TLD and the first subdomain?" What about `foo.bar.co.uk` domains, do you just want "co.uk"? Domains are not "extension based", they're right-to-left hierarchical.

Comment: I think you could substring from the first period until the character before the slash.

Comment: @Kevin people can have as many subdomains as they like tho. a.b.c.d.e.f.g.co.uk

Comment: You really need a lookup table to handle second-level domains - "mod.uk" is what you'd call an extension, but "mod.us" is a legitimate domain name.

Comment: Also be aware that the root may be present in URLs: `http://example.com./path`

Comment: Good writeup by one of the Opera developers on how non-trivial this sort of things is: http://my.opera.com/yngve/blog/show.dml/267415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "http://subdomain.domin.ext/somepath/file.php";
$parse = parse_url($url);
$domain = $parse['host'];
$lastDot = strrpos($domain,'.');
$ext = substr($domain,$lastDot+1);
```

This will get you "ext" (e.g. "com" or "gov"). In the case of something like amazon.co.uk, it will give you "uk". If you need "co.uk", you will need to add logic to detect certain TLDs (e.g. "uk") and go to the second dot on those cases.

Comment: this may be work just for the Top Level Domain .net & .com .. but if you have url like that www.google.co.uk for example it will give the co.uk.. thanks for your answer

Comment: Sounds like you need a lookup table, as Long Ears suggested.

Comment: You could also use substr(strrchr($domain, '.'), 1).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "http://subdomain.domain.ext/somepath/file.php";
$parse = parse_url($url);
$domain = substr(strrchr($parse['host'], '.'), 1);
$domain = substr(strrchr(substr($parse['host'], 0, -strlen($domain)), '.'), 1). '.'. $domain;
if(in_array(strstr($domain, '.', true), array('co', 'com', 'net', 'org', 'edu', 'gov', 'mil')))
{
  $domain = substr(strrchr(substr($parse['host'], 0, -strlen($domain)), '.'), 1). '.'. $domain;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific domain with different TLDs, like `mysite` with `.co.uk` and `.com`, than you can basically do the following:

```
$url = 'http://mysite.co.uk/some-dir/';
$domain_pos = strpos($url, 'mysite');
$domain = substr($url, $domain_pos);
$ext_pos = strpos($domain, '/');
if($ext_pos !== false) { // extra check for paths/sub-dirs
  $domain = substr($domain, 0, $ext_pos); 
}
echo $domain;
```

Returns `mysite.co.uk` or whatever TLD that gets assigned to the `$url`.

Note the extra check for paths and sub directories. :)